# While in another module. How i can access class methods from an instance when im currently in another class?

Tags: python, class, instance

Is it possible to access to class methods from an instance of a class (foo) while in another class (bar), which is in another module?
I know this code is wrong and don't work. But i hope you see what i want to do. Or is there a better way to do it?

file1.py

```
from file2 import instance_of_bar

class Foo(object):

    def kill_bar(self):
        instance_of_bar.kill()

    def baz(self):
        self.kill_bar()


class Bar(object):

    def kill(self):
        print "I'm dead!"
```

file2.py

```
from file1 import *

instance_of_bar = Bar()
instance_of_foo = Foo()
instance_of_foo.baz()
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you pass the instance to the method in question. A modified version of your example code could look like this:

**file1:**

```
class Foo(object):

    def kill_bar(self, bar):
        bar.kill()

class Bar(object):

    def kill(self):
        print "I'm dead!"
```

**file2**:

```
from file1 import *

instance_of_bar = Bar()
instance_of_foo = Foo()
instance_of_foo.kill_bar(instance_of_bar)
```